# OWIN Authentication in MVC 5 Loops while User.IsAuthenticated = false

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I'm trying to implement authentication and authorization in an MVC 5.1 app. The authentication takes place via Facebook that is custom implemented. (I can post that code if needed.) Once FB authenticates and sends back the code and the `Authenticate` method of the auth service is called to sign the user into the application. There is no auth code in the application itself (thus not using Identity or other membership services).

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Connect(string code)
    {
        if (code == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            // get access token
            var accessToken = await nApplication.FacebookClient.AccessTokenAsync(code);
            // get user info from facebook
            var meResult = await nApplication.FacebookClient.MeResultAsync(accessToken);

            nApplication.NRepository.SaveChanges();
            nAuthorization.Authenticate(member);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

`nAuthorization.Authenticate(member);` creates a list of claims and executes OWIN `SignIn`,

```
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, member.Name));
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Member"));
    var claimIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    owinContext.Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true }, claimIdentity);
```

I'm using the `Authorize` attribute from `Mvc` namespace. But at this point `/Profile/Authenticate/` which is my Owin `LoginPath` get's called again and again to redirect the user to FB and return to the `Connect` method above.

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Member")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? id)
```

I've checked the `User` property in the controller and it is not authenticated. I could set that to a new `ClaimsPrincipal` but I'd like the auth code to be independent of the `HttpContext`. And it doesn't seem to be right solution.

My `Startup` class contains:

```
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Profile/Authenticate/"),
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
        ReturnUrlParameter = "next"
    });
```

Maybe I am missing something completely fundamental? Any pointers would help, I've looked through articles such as the following but to no avail:

- http://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/
- http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/asp-net-mvc-5-authentication-breakdown-part-deux

Comment: Have you setup any global filters?

Comment: http://leastprivilege.com/2012/09/24/claimsidentity-isauthenticated-and-authenticationtype-in-net-4-5/ Solves the issue of IsAuthenticated not being true. But still stuck in a loop of 401's from the server.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem, I find if I comment out the LoginPath all works well. with it I get endless loops?

Answer (score 2):

I think this will solve your problem...it worked for me:

Add an empty method in your global.asax.cs file:

```
protected void Session_Start()
{
}
```

for some reason, the asp.net session cookie does not get set at the proper time without this.  The Thinktecture devs think this might be happening if your webapp uses http and your identity provider uses https but I have not verified that yet.